# How to use text.properties in Spring Boot Service?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, multilingual

I have the following code parts:

***text.properties:***

```
exception.NO_ITEM_FOUND.message=Item with email {0} not found
```

***NoSuchElementFoundException:***

```
public class NoSuchElementFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public NoSuchElementFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

***service:***

```
public EmployeeDto findByEmail(String email) {
    return employeeRepository.findByEmail(email)
            .map(EmployeeDto::new)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementFoundException(NO_ITEM_FOUND));
}
```

At this point, I have no idea how to get the NO_ITEM_FOUND message on text.properties based on the user language (for now just default one).

I created the following method, but not sure if I need it or how should I use it.

```
private final MessageSource messageSource;


private String getLocalMessage(String key, String... params){
    return messageSource.getMessage(key,
            params,
            Locale.ENGLISH);
}
```

So, how can I get `NO_ITEM_FOUND` text property from service properly?

Comment: hii, please go through to this document to solve out your issue. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-custom-validation-message-source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need `getLocalMessage` method. Just add an instance variable to your service class:

```
@Value("${exception.NO_ITEM_FOUND.message}")
private String NO_ITEM_FOUND;
```

And annotated with @Value and then use the variable in desirable place of your code:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    @Value("${exception.NO_ITEM_FOUND.message}")
    private String NO_ITEM_FOUND;

    public EmployeeDto findByEmail(String email) {
        return employeeRepository.findByEmail(email)
                .map(EmployeeDto::new)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementFoundException(NO_ITEM_FOUND));
    }

}
```

---

***UPDATE:***

If you have multiple usage of a properties in a Java class, instead of defining separate instance variable for each property, you can *Autowire* ***Environment*** class and then call `getProperty` method just like this in your case:

```
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    private final Environment environment;

    public EmployeeService(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    public EmployeeDto findByEmail(String email) {
        return employeeRepository.findByEmail(email)
                .map(EmployeeDto::new)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementFoundException(environment.getProperty("exception.NO_ITEM_FOUND.message")));
    }

}
```